# Regex to obfuscate substring of a repeating substring

Tags: ruby, regex

Given a string like:

```
abc_1234 xyz def_123aa4a56
```

I want to replace parts of it so the output is:

```
abc_*******z def_*******56
```

The rules are:

1. `abc_` and `def_` are kind of delimiters, so anything between the two are part of the previous delimiter string.
2. The string between the `abc_` and `def_`, and the next delimited string should be replaced by `*`, except for the last 2 characters of that substring. In the above example, `abc_1234 xyz`  (note trailing space), got turned into `abc_*******z`

Comment: You can get the four integers  with `str.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)` but I don't understand how that's related to that which follows "I assume I want:". Best to have a complete example, including the desired return value.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I added some detail : the values following abc_ may be anything (except space), not just digits.

Comment: what should return for `def_332World` or `def_123World` ? `332` and `123` or not consider?

Comment: This very unclear.

Comment: @dawg, I added what I want to do with the input string

Comment: @Zabba Stack Overflow's inline-code formatter strips leading and trailing whitespace, i.e. `\` foo \`` results in `foo`. You have to use `<code> foo </code>` instead to preserve it.

Comment: I have edited out the previous version of the question.  SO keeps edit history for your question (and answers). That history is visible to anyone, so there's no need to keep an old version of a question visible.

Comment: @Stefan, I didn't know about `<code>`. It's a lot easier than using non-breaking spaces, which also work.

Comment: @CarySwoveland easier and less error prone. You can copy and paste the space into your code without flipping tables ;-) [not an actual problem if you have a decent editor capable of highlighting such characters]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
> s
=> "abc_1234 xyz def_123aa4a56"
```

You can do:

```
> s.gsub(/(?<=abc_|def_)(.*?)(..)(?=(?:abc_|def_|$))/) { |m| "*" * $1.length<<$2  }
=> "abc_*******z def_*******56"
```

Comment: That pesky word character `"_"` could be a problem.  It really depends on the details of the specification.

Comment: Thanks, that works well too. I'll modify it to replace all but the last 2 characters

Answer (score 2):

```
prefixes = %w|abc_ def_|
input = "Hello abc_111def_frg def_333World abc_444"
input.gsub(/(#{Regexp.union(prefixes)})../, "\\1**")
#⇒ "Hello abc_**1def_**g def_**3World abc_**4"
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
str = "Hello abc_111def_frg def_333World abc_444"

str.scan(/(?<=abc_|def_)(?:[[:alpha:]]+|[[:digit:]]+)/)
  # => ["111", "frg", "333", "444"]
```

I've assumed the string following `"abc_"` or `"def_"` is either all digits or all letters. It won't work if, for example, you wished to extract `"a1b"` from `"abc_a1b cat"`. You need to better define the rules for what terminates the strings you want.

The regular expression reads, "Following the string `"abc_"` or `"def_"` (a positive lookbehind that is not part of the match), match a string of digits or a string of letters".

Comment: @Zabba your "fix" invalidated this answer. You should not change the gist of a question after answers have been posted and certainly not after accepting one of those answers.

Comment: @stefan, is it better to delete this question?

Comment: @Zabba I don't know. Both the original question and the revised one are interesting. But currently, title, question, comments and answers don't fit together ...